# PHP: Loop array output

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I've got an array which gets appended regularly.
I want to show the content of it like this:

```
$piece1 = array_slice($myarray, 1, 7);  
$piece1output = implode(" ", $piece1);
echo $piece1output;

echo "<br />";

$piece2 = array_slice($myarray, 8, 7);  
$piece2output = implode(" ", $piece2);
echo $piece2output;

echo "<br />";

$piece3 = array_slice($myarray, 15, 7); 
$piece3output = implode(" ", $piece3);
echo $piece3output;
```

As you can see in every piece, I only want to show a specific area of the array.

Piece1 starts at point, piece2 at 8 and piece3 at 15.
The difference between all those start points is 7.

Now I want to create a loop for this, which automatically shows the whole content of the array like in the code above.

Thank you.

Comment: Why you need loop..? The implode simply takes all element and glue them together. You can do like this - $pieceoutput = implode(" ", $myarray);
echo $pieceoutput;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
    for($i=1;$<=count($myarray);$i +=7){
    $piece = array_slice($myarray, $i, 7);  
    $pieceoutput = implode(" ", $piece );
    echo $pieceoutput;

    echo "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: `$myarray.length` is JavaScript.

Comment: My apologies. I wrote it by mistake. Now, I have edited my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. Please vote it up and mark it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=count($myarray); $i+=7){

    $piece = array_slice($myarray, $i, 7);  
    $output = implode(" ", $piece);

    echo $output."<br />";

}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks very logical. I added it to my code but when I load my site now the browser tries to load the site and then it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me.  Check your `semi-colons` in the `for()`